# display hyperlink as friendly-url using mod_rewrite, but there is something wrong

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I want to convert the links(hyperlink) in my script to friendly-url using mod_rewrite, and I have the following example.

**.htaccess Code:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index/(.*)$ index.php?usr=$1 [L]
```

**PHP, html Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
          echo $_GET['usr'];
        ?>
        <a href="index.php?usr=10">Click Here</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I need is this code(hyperlink) when click on it.

```
<a href="index.php?usr=10">Click Here</a>
```

Link appears as follows in the address bar

```
domain.com/project/index/10  // `project` is the main folder of the script
```

But unfortunately, when I click on the previous link, appears in the address bar as follows

```
domain/project/index.php?usr=10
```

And now, what is the reason of appear the link as old form(without friendly-url) instead of appears as (friendly-url) ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to use the URL you want:

```
<a href="index/10">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is, I have many links(hyperlink) in my script like that, and that need to modified every hyperlink in script to friendly-url, to appears in address bar as friendly-url, and this requires effort to do so. Is there a way to do this programmatically.

Comment: Not with `mod_rewrite`.  `sed -i 's/href="index.php?usr=([0-9]*)"/href="index/\1"' <FILES>` might do the trick to change all your files.  That regex may need modifying to avoid matching the wrong parts and [may fail entirely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what is mod_sed, can you please write the Appropriate .htaccess code for my case in your answer not in a comment. thank you

Comment: Not `mod_sed`, just `sed`.  [It's a command line program](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).  And I just realised I missed the `/g` off the end of that `sed` command.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is the first time I hear about sed.  Where do you write these this code `sed -i 's/href="index.php?usr=([0-9]*)"/href="index/\1"' <FILES>` ?